# How to force field mappings with a ManyToMany relationship on same model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a fairly simple model representing users:

```py
class Person(AbstractUser):
    students = models.ManyToManyField("web.Person", through="Supervision")
    ...
```

with a many-to-many relationship to itself...

```py
class Supervision(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('web.Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="supervisor")
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey('web.Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['student', 'supervisor']]
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "{supervisor} supervises {student} ({id})".format(
            supervisor=self.supervisor, student=self.student, id=self.pk
        )
```

The problem comes when I create a relation between 2 persons:

```py
>>> prof = Person.objects.get(last_name="prof")
>>> student = Person.objects.get(last_name="student")  
>>> prof.students.add(student)
>>> prof.save()
>>> Supervision.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Supervision: student, student (1130) supervises prof, prof (97) (2)>]>
```

It seems that Django swaps the relation by default.

I tried to swap the related names in the class definition of the Supervision:

```py
class Supervision(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('web.Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student")
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey('web.Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="supervisor")
```

But it does not help. How can I get Django to put the fields in the correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that Django is *swapping* the relation as you say. The thing is Django simply doesn't know which foreign key is for what part of the relation. You can specify the [`through_fields` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) in your `ManyToManyField` so that Django may know which field is for the source and which is for the target:

```
class Person(AbstractUser):
    students = models.ManyToManyField("self", through="Supervision", through_fields=('supervisor', 'student'), symmetrical=False)
```

> **Note**: I changed `web.Person` to `self` since that is a better way to specify a foreign key / m2m to the same model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you edit it and add `symmetrical=False`. Otherwise, I get two relations created (a correct one and one in the wrong order).